# codehs how to toggle . createElement to show and hide a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

can someone help me I cannot figure out why the first 2 .createElements don't show but the last three show?

here is my code also here is the link to an example project on codehs https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/javascript-graphics-vvD5CX

```
var atStoreButton = document.createElement("Button");
   atStoreButton.innerHTML = "At The Store";
document.body.appendChild(atStoreButton);
$("atStoreButton").toggle("slow");
    
var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Sign In";
document.body.appendChild(button);
$("button").toggle("slow");

var homeButton = document.createElement("Button");
    homeButton.innerHTML = "Home";
document.body.appendChild(homeButton);
$("homeButton").toggle("slow");

var addAnItem = document.createElement("Button");
    addAnItem.innerHTML = "add Item";
document.body.appendChild(addAnItem);
$("addAnItem").toggle("slow");

var log0ut = document.createElement("Button");
    log0ut.innerHTML = "Log Out";
document.body.appendChild(log0ut);
$("log0ut").toggle("slow");
log0ut.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: FYI - All these `$(...).toggle("slow");` don't actually do anything. The only one that does is `$("button").toggle("slow");` which selects all buttons already on the page. Don't think you want to include the double quotes and reference the buttons directly i.e. `$(atStoreButton).toggle("slow");`

Comment: What is the styling of `.slow`?

Comment: can you give a little more info I'm not quite sure what you are asking